# I am unable to use logical name in case of descriptive programming in UFT

Tags: automation, automated-tests, qtp

I can do the following in QTP

```
Browser("A").Page("P").WebEdit("W").ToString()
```

But i am not able to do the following

```
set a=Browser("A").Page("P").WebEdit("innertext:=zoo")
```

a.ToString()

Please tell how can we give logical name in case of descriptive programming. I have to print the logical name a (in this case)

Answer (score 2):

```
Set objLogical = Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebEdit("Search")
Print objLogical.ToString()
```

**Output = Search edit box**

**Reason** = It was from object repository and able to get the name associated with that.

```
Set objLogical = Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebEdit("html tag:=input","name:=q")
Print objLogical.ToString()
```

**Output = [ WebEdit ] edit box**

**Reason** = There is no name assigned, instead properties are defined explicitly within an object itself.

What exactly are you trying to solve? Can you be more elaborate with the situation? So that, a research/answer would be more appropriate.

**EDITED**

```
If objLogical.Exist(0) Then
    strLogicalName = objLogical.GetROProperty("title")
    Reporter.ReportEvent micPass,"Check existance of [" & strLogicalName & "]","[" & strLogicalName & "] exists."
Else
    Reporter.ReportEvent micFail,"Check existance of [" & objLogical.ToString()& "]","[" & objLogical.ToString()& "] not exists."
End If
```

Use **value/title/accname or any properties** which had the meaningful name of the object and pass the same to your report event. In my case, I chose title **

I have hard coded objLogical for understanding purpose only. You define at your own convenient.

The bottom line is you cannot get the logical name from the descriptive approach. Instead, query the properties which had a meaningful name.

Comment: I am trying to check existence of an object. If an object does not exist then, the message should be "Webedit objLogical was not displayed". I should not hadrcode objLogical. I have to take the logical name, if it can be assigned to the description of WebEdit in descriptive programming

Comment: Your `else` statement will not work because you are only assigning a value to `strLogicalName` in the `If` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `ToString` function doesn't give the logical name, it gives the name of the object in the repository followed by the object type. If the object doesn't have an OR name it will use the type in square brackets.

For example, if you go to http://www.example.com and learn the *More information...* link, then rename the `Link` to "*More info*" you'll see the following behaviour.

```
Print "OR toString - " & Browser("B").Page("P").Link("More info").ToString()
Print "OR logical name - " & Browser("B").Page("P").Link("More info").GetROProperty("logical name")
Print "DP toString - " & Browser("B").Page("P").Link("text:=More.*").ToString()
Print "DP logical name - " & Browser("B").Page("P").Link("text:=More.*").GetROProperty("logical name")
```

> OR toString - More info link
>   OR logical name - More information...
>   DP toString - [ Link ] link
>   DP logical name - More information...